# Match capture group to given pattern in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame 'tdf' with a column "Cars" where the values are 4 letters and then 1-6 numbers.

```
Cars
JAXT450678
KYXS 56746
LMOP01456
...
```

I have compiled the regex to match it:
 `r'(?=[a-zA-Z]{4}\s*\d{1,6}\b)([a-zA-Z]{4})(\s?\d+)'`

What I want to do is strip the whitespace out and then make sure that if there are less than 6 digits in the second group, insert 0's starting at the second group until a count of 6 is reached, such that the result is:

```
Cars
JAXT450678
KYXS056746
LMOP001456
...
```

Any help is appreciated. I have tried playing around with `.replace` and `.sub` and can get it to replace the entire match, but I don't know how to reference the group and have it dynamically match.

`tdf = tdf.replace(r'(?=[a-zA-Z]{4}\s*\d{1,6}\b)([a-zA-Z]{4})(\s?\d+)','000000', regex = True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Cars'] = df['Cars'].str.replace(r'^([a-zA-Z]{4})\s*(\d{1,6})$', lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).zfill(6)))
```

**Details**

- `^` - matches the start of a string
- `([a-zA-Z]{4})` - Group 1: four letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{1,6})` - Group 2: 1 to 6 digits
- `$` - end of string.

The `lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).zfill(6))` callable concats Group 1 value and Group 2 value that is padded with zeros up to 6 positions.

Since `\s*` is out of parentheses, the whitespaces matched with this pattern are omitted from the result.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the detailed explanation. Is there a way to make it return a list of those that are not matched and their positions? 

If this is code heavy I will obviously open a new question.

Comment: Like an output of any in the column that didn't return a match or weren't changed and their respective row position.
Say, for example, I had an odd one that was `M2XL009233`, which wouldn't match because it doesn't start with 4 letters. Could I return that car and its row number?

Comment: @poorpractice `df3[~df3['Cars'].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]{4}\s*\d{1,6}$')]` returns me `Cars
2  M2XL009233` - the `M2XL009233` is at Row 3 (Index 2) in my test data.

Answer (score 2):

Use replace to replace white space and zfill to fill number part of the string,

```
df['Cars'].str.replace(' ', '').apply(lambda x: x[:4] + x[4:].zfill(6))

0    JAXT450678
1    KYXS056746
2    LMOP001456
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a one-liner, but you can avoid `apply`:

```
s = df.Cars.str.slice(4).str.strip().str.zfill(6)
df.Cars.str.slice(0,4) + s
```

Output:

```
0    JAXT450678
1    KYXS056746
2    LMOP001456
Name: Cars, dtype: object
```